# Bernouilli variables - bias and variance of estimator

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mathematical-statistics, bernoulli-distribution

Reading through [this](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Elarry/=stat705/Lecture9.pdf) I work on Example 1 in 3. Consistency.

> $X_{1},... , X_{n} ∼ Bernoulli(p)$. The mle $\hat{p}$ has bias 0 and variance $p(1−p)/n \rightarrow 0$.
> Here $\hat{p} =
> \sum_{i} Xi/n$. So $\hat{p} \rightarrow p$ and is consistent. Now let $\psi = log(p/(1 − p))$. Then
> $\hat{\psi} = log(\hat{p}/ (1 − \hat{p}))$. Now $\hat{ψ} = g(\hat{p})$ where $g(p) = log(p/(1 − p))$. By the continuous mapping
> theorem, $\hat{\psi} \rightarrow \psi$ so this is consistent.

Up to there, no problem.

> Now consider
> $\hat{p} = \frac{\sum_{i}X_{i}+1}{n+1}$

I try to retrieve bias and variance as expressed in the paper :

> $Bias = E[\hat{p}]-p=-\frac{p-1}{n(n+1)} \rightarrow 0$
>
> $Var = \frac{p(1-p)}{n}\rightarrow 0$

However my calculation gives

$Bias = E[\frac{\sum_{i}X_{i}+1}{n+1}]-p = (E[\sum_{i}X_{i}]+1)/(n+1)-p$

by the linearity of expected value. Moreover, the mle estimator $\hat{p}=\sum_{i}X_{i}/n$ has bias 0, so that

$E[\sum_{i}X_{i}/n]-p=0$ and $E[\sum_{i}X_{i}]=np$

which i plug in the expression of bias for the third estimator :

$(E[\sum_{i}X_{i}]+1)/(n+1)-p= \frac{np+1}{n+1}-p=\frac{np+1-p(n+1)}{n+1}=\frac{1-p}{n+1}$.

Where is my calculation wrong ? Similarly how to derive the variance ?

Comment: For $\hat p=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(\sum X_i+1\right)$, indeed it is true that bias is $E(\hat p-p)=\frac{np+1}{n+1}-p=\frac{1-p}{n+1}$.

And $\operatorname{Var}(\hat p)=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum X_i\right)=\frac{np(1-p)}{(n+1)^2}$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom are you with me against the book ?

Comment: There can only be one correct answer, right?

Comment: absolutely your right